# Why I am not getting datas in other activity from previous activity using interface in android

Tags: java, android, java-8, interface

Though I know get and put extras we can use in intent to pass to other activity but I am just trying whether it's possible to store and get the data through interface. I stored the data but in other activity, I am not  able to get the data.

Below is what I tired.

```
interface PassDataToOtherActivity {
    public void passData(String data);

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    default void setData(String s) {

    }



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PassDataToOtherActivity {
    private TextView textView;
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.first_text);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        textView.setText("Hello Test");
        setData(textView.getText().toString());
        passData(textView.getText().toString());


    }

    @Override
    public void passData(String data) {
//override methods
    }
}



public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PassDataToOtherActivity {
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView_2);
    }

    @Override
    public void passData(String data) { //why i am not getting the datas from previous activity?
        textView.setText(data);

    }

    @Override
    public void setData(String data) { //why I am not able to get the datas from previous activity?
        textView.setText(data);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using put extra and getExtra, you can achieve through Singleton class.

```
public class DataHolder {

    private static final DataHolder instance = new DataHolder();

    public static DataHolder getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private String data;
    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Now you can set the data and get the data in other class. Here I didn't used any other android provided api such as Preference or intent components to pass and get the data.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView textView;
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.first_text);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView.setText("Hello Test");
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DataHolder.getInstance().setData(textView.getText().toString());
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });



    }
}



public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView_2);
        textView.setText(DataHolder.getInstance().getData());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Implementing interface on a class doesn't mean it would get the call automatically.

E.g. A class is only able to pass data to the B class if the B class:

- Implements the interface.
- A class holds an instance of the interface which is pointing to class B's object

In your example. the instance of SecondActivity is not created by you hence it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should use extras on intents, it is a lot more efficient.
Pass data from MainActivity :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("TEXT_TO_PASS", "Hello Test");
startActivity(intent);
```

Then retrieve it from SecondActivity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    String dataPassed = getIntent().getStringExtra("TEXT_TO_PASS");
}
```

Explore more about passing data between activities [here](https://medium.com/@peterekeneeze/passing-data-between-activities-2d0ef122f19d)

Comment: I already specified in first line that, I don't want to use put and getExtras. If I can use that, then what's the use of interface then?

Comment: Well the interface is useless in that case. Interface is a contract which forces both of your activities to implement those methods, but they are not connected at any point. Basically, an interface is used to be sure classes have the same behaviour and methods, it does not store data.

If you want to bypass extras, you can create a handler class, that is nothing more than a java class in the one you will affect some data in attributes.

Comment: `I don't want to use put and getExtras` tough luck, because you should be using intent extras, otherwise your app will get crashes that you didn't expect `If I can use that, then what's the use of interface then?` the interface you added is pointless as you won't be able to get a reference to the other Activity, so the answer is "I have no idea, but you shouldn't have been doing that anyway".

Comment: We can achieve through singleton class @CorentinHoudayer

Comment: @Shadow You're right, I would go for this if I had to do it.

Answer (score 1):

**No, it's not possible to pass data between activities via interface.**

The reason to it, to work with interface, interface object must be initialised as we do it during onAttach() method when passing data between two fragments.

But in case of Activity, one cannot pass the context to initialise.

```
    class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements myInterface {
          onCreate(){
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
              if (fragment != null) {
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragmentTag);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
      }

      @Override
      public void onChange(String s) {
      // your retrieved code
      }
    }


    class MyFragment extends Fragment {

     private MyInterface interf ;
     @Override
        public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);
            interf = (myInterface) context;
        }
        onActivityCreated(){
         interf.onChange("Hello");
        }

    }

  public interface myInterface {
    void onChange();
  }
```

Comment: It's technically *possible* but it would involve statics and it would be generally unsafe.